# how to do order by in Multiple Collection

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

```
public class Test
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Test1> test1{get;set;}
}

public class Test1
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Test2> test2{get;set;}
}

public class Test2
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Test3> test3{get;set;}
}

public class Test3
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
}
```

This is how my model look like, i want to order by this list using name column

```
IList<Test> test = ... ;

test = test .OrderBy(p => p.test1.select(o=>o.test2.Select(m => m.test3.Select(x => x.name))));
```

i am doing Order by for the list from cosmos db

but it throws some error,Please someone help me to solve this

```
{
 "message": "Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be mapped to a document path.\"}]}\r\nActivityId: 3761139f-cc41-49a5-874e-1b62efa8a8d5, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Windows/10.0.18362 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.8.1",
  "version": 0,
  "errorCode": null,
  "result": null,
  "errors": []
}
```

Comment: can you please add sample input data so that easy to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code does this line compile at all?

```
test = test .OrderBy(p => p.Test1.Test2.Select(m => m.Test3.Select(x => x.name)));
```

> p.Test1

I assume this is a typo here looking at your class it should be test1 (not the class name with a capital T).

If the above was a typo and it indeed is p.test1 in your actual code, then again looking at your class test1 is an Enumeration you can not say

> test1.test2

I think the whole thing will not compile. Now coming back to your original question, you can sort test3 based on its name, and then assign the sorted list to Test2 objects test3 member, but its kind of weird if you say you want to sort test by the name property of test3.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code, Its working

```
     IList<Test> test = new List<Test>() { new Test() { id=1, test1=new List<Test1>() {
            new Test1(){ id=1, test2=new List<Test2> (){ new Test2() {  id=1, test3=new List<Test3> (){
                new Test3() { id=1,name="Hello"} ,
                new Test3() { id=2,name="welcome"} }
            } } } }
        } };

        test = test.OrderBy(p => p.test1.Select(m => m.test2.Select(x => x.test3.Select(a => a.name)))).ToList();
```